# access a Database scalar value function in Entity framework 6 within linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6, user-defined-functions

What steps i should follow to use the following sql scalar value function within entity framework.

```
select dbo.GetDefaultAccount(5,1,48)
```

I tried creating a static class under the same namespace of the edmx and defining the function as following

```
    [EdmFunction("Model.Store", "GetDefaultAccount")]
    public static int? GetDefaultAccount(int id, Int16 type, int assocId)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

While accessing it from linq like below

```
  var Accountno = (from s in dbcontext.TranSetups select new { Accountno = CutomEdmxFunctions.GetDefaultAccount(5, 1, 48) })
                       .FirstOrDefault().Accountno;
```

I get the following error

> cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression because no overload matches the passed arguments

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, working scalar-valued functions in Entity Framework is not as easy as it supposed to be. After a long googling I found only two methods to work with scalar-valued functions, best described [here](https://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/first-impressions-of-database-first-development-with-entity-framework-5-in-visual-studio-2012/), but remember: all edits to the .edmx file will be lost when you update the EDM from the database. You will have to re-edit the .edmx file each time. Good luck.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.   
Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.